# C# Image Edge Feathering

Tags: c#, gdi+, image-manipulation

**DISCLAIMER: This code is terrible and should not be used in production. It's testing a proof of concept.**

I want to create an image like below using C# the key points are the feathered edges and the transparency of the whole image.

[image]

Here is my result so far

[image]

As you can see the edges are feathered. My question is, does anyone know how to feather the edges using pure C# and maintain transparency, currently I am using a 3rd party library with some pretty nasty looking code?

Would be interested if there is a better approach to this full stop.

Here is some of the code I have been using.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
// Transparent Background
SolidBrush semiTransparentPen = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(60, 31, 31, 31));
graphics.FillRectangle(semiTransparentPen, 0f, 0f, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

// Feather edges
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(bitmap);
Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(bitmap);

fipbmp.makeEdgesTransparentHorzSigma(bitmap1, 4, 4);
fipbmp.makeEdgesTransparentVertSigma(bitmap2, 4, 4);
fipbmp.MergeBmp(bitmap, bitmap1, bitmap2);

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

byte[] buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: just a question, is there a project requirement to use GDI+?

Comment: No, more interested in performance and efficiency

Answer (score 0):

You may find this blog post which I once wrote useful: [Soft Edged Images in GDI+](http://danbystrom.se/2008/08/24/soft-edged-images-in-gdi/). That will show you a lot of what you need to know. In order to create smooth edges on an arbitrary shape you will also need a smoothing filter (which you'll then need to apply to the alpha channel), which you can read about [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpfilters.aspx).